# how do i get values from array/object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I call the upload function and it returns a variable. when I do `var_dump($x)` it shows the following:

```
{"files":[{"name":"1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_28860.jpg","size":0,"type":"image\/jpeg","error":"abort","delete_url":"http:\/\/www.xxx.com\/upload\/uploader\/server\/php\/?file=1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_28860.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}array(1) {
["files"]=>
    array(1) {
     [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (6) {
     ["name"]=> string(47) "1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_28860.jpg"
     ["size"]=> int(0)
     ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
     ["error"]=> string(5) "abort"
     ["delete_url"]=> string(104) "http://www.xxx.com/upload/uploader/server/php/?file=1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_28860.jpg"
     ["delete_type"]=> string(6) "DELETE"
    }
 }
}
```

I tried `var_dump(json_decode($x))` and the result is NULL.

My question is how do I get the value name from this???

tried these two:

```
echo $x->files[0]->name;
echo " ********************** ";
echo $x['files'][0]->name;
echo " ********************** ";
```

and the result is

```
{"files":[{"name":"1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_14299.jpg","size":78289,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"http:\/\/www.xxx.com\/upload\/uploader\/server\/php\/files\/1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_14299.jpg","thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/www.xxx.com\/upload\/uploader\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_14299.jpg","delete_url":"http:\/\/www.xxx.com\/upload\/uploader\/server\/php\/?file=1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_14299.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}{"files":[{"name":"1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_12920.jpg","size":0,"type":"image\/jpeg","error":"abort","delete_url":"http:\/\/www.xxx.com\/upload\/uploader\/server\/php\/?file=1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_12920.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}
********************** 
{"files":[{"name":"1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_15697.jpg","size":0,"type":"image\/jpeg","error":"abort","delete_url":"http:\/\/www.xxx.com\/upload\/uploader\/server\/php\/?file=1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_15697.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}1004046_469695273124093_104592888_n_1_15697.jpg
**********************
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried:

```
$name_val = $x->files[0]->name;
```

Comment: Think it might be $x["files"][0]->name ... top level element appears to be an array

Comment: what is generating $x in the first place? can you provide more context?

Comment: there is a string before the first array. I did json_decode the split it by } then I treated the right hand side as an array `$x['files'][0]->name gave me the result

Answer (score 0):

```
$_FILES['files']['error'];
$_FILES['files']['name'];
```